# 起動するServletをサブドメインで判断したい

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

お世話になっております。

現在GoogleAppEngineを利用してサーバーサイドを制作しています。 
Servletのバージョンは2.5です。

APIなどを作成する上でapi.example.comの形でサブドメイン形式にしようと思ってます。

そこで

通常ページ: example.com 
APIページ: api.example.com 
管理ページ: admin.example.com

のイメージでサブドメインでServletを分けたいと思います。

ソースファイルのパッケージ構成はクラス名を統一したいので 
ページ用Servlet: com.exampleパッケージ 
API用Servlet: com.example.apiパッケージ 
管理用Servlet: com.example.adminパッケージ 
このように分けて配置しようと考えています。

そこで質問なのですが、 
newsの表示: example.com/news 
newsのAPI: api.example.com/news 
news管理画面: admin.example.com/news 
とURLを構成する場合、どのようにアクセスを判断してServletを切り分けるのがいいのでしょうか？

`<url-pattern>`を使用するにもドメイン以下が同じのためうまく切り分けれていない状況です。 
`<url-pattern>`で切り分けられれば`<security-constraint>`を使用するときも楽だなとは思っています。

1つの手段としては 
filterクラスを定義し、サブドメインを解析してサーブレットにforwardさせる 
方法ならできると思うのですが、news以外にもコンテンツが増えた場合、それに合わせてフィルタークラスも増えていくのがナンセンスだと思っています。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: url-patternは今回の用途に使えない、というのは[こちらのコメント](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876023/i-want-to-switch-servlet-by-subdomain)にあるとおりですね。また、Filterを用いる場合の実装としては、正規表現風に書くと (.+).example.com/(.+)  なURLを、例えば /$1/$2 へforwardするようになると思います。懸念されているような、サブディレクトリ増加に合わせてFilterを追加実装しなければならないような自体にはならないと考えているのですが、いかがでしょう。(その他、敢えてサブドメインに拘る必要はあるのか？というのも個人的には気になりますが。)

Comment: url-patternの件は回答をいただいた通りでした。Filterの件ですが、参考に実装してみます。サブドメインの件はURLのディレクトリ構成をシンプルにするためです。